# What does it mean: They "are not in it with" something?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I do not get the meaning of the expression: "They are not in it with the bees". 
I need an equivalent that can be understood by everybody.

This is the full text:

ALIN CAILLAS, L’Apiculteur, p. 464, estimates that a bee carrying .0007 oz. of honey at a load will make 12,632 trips to fill a section 4 inches square and 1 inch thick. If it average 5/8 of a mile to the trip, it will travel as much as a third of the way around the world. In a colony of 120,000 bees, if 80,000 are fielders, and each one makes 10 trips of 5/8 of a mile daily, the total travel for the day will be more than twice the distance to the moon. **As flyers, the Wright brothers are not in it with the bees.** [If a bee carried .0007 oz. of nectar it would have to make nearly twice 12,000 trips in order to make enough honey to fill a section 4 inches square and 1 inch thick. — ED.]
Source: [Gleanings in Bee Culture, March 15, 1911, p 160, bottom of the first column](http://hdl.handle.net/2027/uma.ark:/13960/t3st7w20b?urlappend=%3Bseq=168).

Comment: How  very interesting indeed. These annals are pre-World War I. I cannot locate the exact page. I wonder how they put these things together in those days. I guess participants sent in their ideas by snail mai?? Robert, are you an English speaker? This English is not idiomatic but **it means" the Wright brothers are not in the SAME LEAGUE as the bees. :) The bees are faster is the idea.

Comment: I don't recall ever encountering this usage before, but I'm sure the intended meaning is what I'd be more likely to express *(informally)* as *The Wright brothers are **not exactly [right] up there** with the bees.* That's to say, they're *not in the same league* as the bees.

Comment: @Lambie: Dunno about *bees are **faster***. I admit I've no idea how fast early Wright planes or bees travel, but the context seems to be more about *carrying / cargo capacity* (relative to total weight, I suppose). Or perhaps it's about *total distance travelled*.

Comment: In any event, Mr. Root says below that he has a hard time understanding the fellow's comments and those of his countrymen....I can delete that post in French but I just wanted to show it to the OP. Gosh, my Dad attended Amherst agricultural some years after that. In the late teens. :)

Comment: The meaning could be that the Wright brothers did not fly as often as a bee?!

Answer (score 2):

> As flyers, the Wright brothers are not in it with the bees.

The phrase means that the Wright brothers are not as good flyers as bees are.

To be

> in it

is to be able to participate, compete, or be at the same level as *something*, thus the lottery phrase

> You got to be in it to win it!

Your phrase is saying bees are far superior flyers than the Wright brothers were.

> As flyers, the Wright brothers are *not in league with* bees.
>   As flyers, the Wright brothers are *not comparable to* bees.

Bees can fly vast distances while carrying over 50% of their body weight in nectar, whereas the Wright brothers could at best manage a few hundred feet of flight at very low altitude with minimal payload [here](http://wright.nasa.gov/airplane/powered.html).

Comment: The text is from 1911. At that time the Wright brothers flew for hours without landing and their planes could carry over 200 kg of payload, excluding the weight of the pilot.

Comment: Suggestion: "are not in league with bees" sounds like there's no collusion.  Better: "are not in a league with bees" or "are not in the same league as bees".